# Is changing primary_key value equivalent to destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-migration

Consider a `Book` model with `primary_key` for convenience set to the column `title` instead of the default column `id`. See [this article](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/) and at [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Suppose that there is a `has_many :through` association between this model and a second `Reader` model. Using `dependent: :destroy` in the `Book` and `Reader` models would guarantee that deleting a `reader` all the associations would be deleted and that deleting a `book` all the associations would be deleted.

The `Book` model records the 100 most read books, and the list is updated every month. 
Updating the list would involve updating the `title` and the `purchasings` attributes, so it may happen that a `title` that the month before was ranked 100, the next month can be ranked out of 100 and thus out of database.

Being the association reader/book based upon a `foreign_key` (the 101th book's name) that does not exist anymore, would the association itself be deleted? 
 Or the association would somehow survive because there was not an effective deletion in `Book` (`Book` which instead preserves 100 items and their original `ids`)?

Comment: Please, code, before and after. Its difficult to understand your questions based on suposed scenarios.

Comment: What you call 'supposed scenarios' others call 'design', which often comes before coding. The question is simple: changing the primary_key's value of a book (or user) would have the same effect of a deletion (deleting a book/user and creating a new one)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. 
I reproduced the conditions using the Relationship model and the has_many :through association described in [M.Hartl's tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users): a user can follow (and be followed by) another user using the Relationship association.

I had 100 users and created users 101 and 102 (id 101 and 102). 
I followed `user 1` as `user 101`, and as `user 1` I followed `user 101`. 
I changed the id of `user 101` into 103.

After this change `user 1` relationships dropped by 2 (-1 following and -1 followers). 
However `Relationship.count` is still the same: the relationships between `User 1` and `User 101` were not destroyed although `User.find(101)` reports "couldn't find User with id=101".

Then I changed the id of `user 102` into 101. 
To my surpise `user 102` inherited the relationships of the original `user 101`, and `user 1` recovered the lost relationships .

So, in conclusion, associations are based on the primary keys. 
If a primary key value of a record is changed, the original associations of that record are not more linked to the new primary key value.

What puzzles me is that these associations are not destroyed although in the User model there is a `has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy` line, and although the old id refers to a user which does not exist any more in the database.